# Rate The Viability Of My Phish-Proof System

Tags: phishing

I have recently finished building my first (and so far only) phish-proof login system and I would like the experts to test it. The system is hosted at http://www.daera.net/noph/nophlogin.htm

Is it easy or hard to copy the visual content of my page? Please state your answer for novice web programmers and experts. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly does your "protection" work ? I don't have time to reverse-engineer your Javascript, but really this offers no protection as the whole page is not even served over HTTPS.

Comment: The protection works by ensuring (through the page and the server) that the user is present on the authentic URL. If an unauthentic URL is hosting the coding, the server would send a warning message to the viewer of the page that it is a phish page. The page has no tech to stop data theft during communication, rather it is focussed on stopping (or making it hard) building a fake copy of the visual content of the page.

Comment: Why would the legitimate server ever be involved ? The page is attacker-controlled, so (unless he's really a idiot) he would be POSTing the login form to his own malicious server which will just return an "incorrect username/password" error to appear legitimate while secretly storing the credentials.

Comment: Can you please try and do that and see how the page looks like after you are done with that? I understand that is what phishing basically is, but the page's visual content would change if you host it on an illegitimate url.

Comment: As I said, I unfortunately don't have time to reverse-engineer the Javascript and modify the code to no longer change the appearance of the page if the URL doesn't match, but a dedicated attacker will definitely do. This is, at best, security by obscurity which isn't considered good practice.

Comment: copy->paste the page source, remove the cry.js ref. have I missed something here?

Comment: Jay ... may I ask you to try doing that and informing us of the result? Andre Borie, it is partly security by obscurity and partly ... well ... depending on the server to authenticate the location of the webpage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Sec.SE is not a testing service, nor for polls. Please write out the specific points of your "system" that you would like to ask about, and ask a specific, answerable question.

Comment: @AviD: Understood. I will change the wording of my question to make it more direct and precise.

Comment: Can't I just build my own web page that looks the same using your CSS & imagery? Might take a 20mins but there's no countering that. Are you just trying to stop things like the tools in Kali that mimic sites? SET framework? I forget what it's called...

Comment: I think you can make it on topic if you frame this more of  "Does my home made security mechanism provide security" and rather than invite people to break your site by obscurity show how you've built it and invite answers

Comment: Regarding your obfuscation, I get the feeling I can simply host http://daera.net/response.php?rnd=0.7629104312509298&req=2&loc=xfg%21LbfaP%21Vfu~%5E%60Xi0%5D_aPmpUX_wiu%5B as a text file and change part of var _0x13ca to point to my own domain to bypass your test

Comment: @Morgoroth: Can you please try doing that and see if it looks like the target site? I know it is 100% possible to bypass the checks I have placed and forego them, the only question (like all security systems) is _how hard and complex_ would that effort be? That is what the question title is about.

Comment: It is a disappointment that so far I have only received comments ***discussing*** the subject, but nobody has come up with a practical effort and stood out to say "look! this is a perfect visual copy of your webpage!" :(

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect people on a question and answer site to spend time building a copy of a site. There is evidence that getting users to recognise features of a page is ineffective in preventing phishing attacks, so it's more the concept that is flawed, than a specific implementation. However, it would take a web designer a couple of hours at most to implement a page that looked the same to average users. The animated text is not difficult to replicate with, for example, an animated gif.

Comment: The site have been taken offline. I assume you obfuscate the site to load the contents, which is useless against automation tools that load browser that render javascript, then capture all contents(e.g. logo, image,etc)  download from the server. From there, a phisher can use the image to reconstruct the site.  There is little need to make it looks perfect, most user just login and ignore all the visual checking features, nobody will cares if complicate check vanish.

Comment: @mootmoot: I took the system offline because the question was deemed off topic and closed. So there was no point left to continue hosting that system because nobody was interested in taking it apart. Btw the main idea behind the whole thing was to not keep anything hardcoded in the page and take everything from the server through ajax. But before sending the data to the target page, the server would first determine which address the requests were coming from. So if the attacker copied all the coding and hosted it on his site, the request would come from a different site and data be denied.

Comment: @YoustayIgo : I wouldn't say your concept is wrong. You should check selenium webdriver(or phantomjs) and see how it is easily automated to peeks on your browser traffics. In addition,  obfuscation is never a good idea in web publishing. It add little obstacles to phisher but trouble for malware analysis.

Answer (score 6):

> The protection works by ensuring (through the page and the server) that the user is present on the authentic URL. If an unauthentic URL is hosting the coding, the server would send a warning message to the viewer of the page that it is a phish page.

Therefore the protection itself is ensured by the server.  But if the server is not legitimate, relying in its verification is useless.

All that is necessary for a person to set up a phishing copy of your server is to modify the code to pass the verification.

In general, you need to have a Trusted Third Party to verify the identity (you cannot ask the phisher himself if he's legitimate!).  This is what is done e.g. for SSL certificates, which are signed by a CA trusted by all major browsers.

Comment: May I please ask you to try doing that and informing us of the result of your endeavor? As I have stated in reply to a comment, the technique is simply an effort to stop the malicious person from faking the visual content of the page. If you are successfully able to fake it, then my phish prevention technique is indeed useless.